# What will happen in the background, when we update a record in a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, update

I have a table `company` like,

```
id  |  name  | age | address   | salary
----+--------+-----+-----------+--------
 1  | Ganesh |  32 | Chennai   |  20000
 2  | Allen  |  25 | Chennai   |  15000
 3  | Teddy  |  23 | Chennai   |  20000
 4  | Mark   |  25 | Chennai   |  65000
 5  | Paul   |  32 | Chennai   |  20000
 6  | Allen  |  25 | Chennai   |  15000
 7  | Teddy  |  23 | Chennai   |  20000
 8  | Paul   |  32 | Chennai   |  20000
 9  | Allen  |  25 | Chennai   |  15000
 10 | Teddy  |  23 | Chennai   |  20000
```

Now, what will happen in the background, when I update any one (or more)  record(s) in this table?

```
update company set address = 'California' where id = 5;
```

My real doubt is, whether it will delete the whole old record and insert a record newly with  given value or it just replace the given value in the specified column?

If the record is deleted for update, then the memory remain there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a new row version will be created by an update to support [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html). This might not happen under [certain conditions](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD) e.g. if the update does not change any indexed column.

The space  occupied by the old row version will be freed by the [auto-vacuum process](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) and re-used for new data once there are no more transactions that would see that version.